# Why does the Open Goldberg score have a G rather than A in bar 9 of variation 25?

Tags: musescore

In the Open Goldberg score of Bach's Goldberg-Variationen (edited by Werner Schweer, peer-reviewed on MuseScore), which can be found on IMSLP, in bar 9 of Variation 25, the 6th note in the right hand is a G. However, other scores that I've seen have an A, and every performance I've heard uses an A.

Is the G a typo, or is there some evidence that Bach intended a G?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

It's an error.

#### The Evidence

Here is the measure in question from the first edition of the Goldberg Variations.<sup>1</sup> Note that it includes the A rather than G.

[image: Goldberg Variations, First edition, variation 25, measure 9]

What establishes this as correct is the existence of the *handexemplar* — an annotated version of the first edition, in Bach's handwriting.<sup>2</sup> Here is the same measure from that edition. Notice there are no annotations or corrections.

[image: Goldberg Variations, handexemplar, variation 25, measure 9]

However, to reinforce things, Bach did make other annotations elsewhere in variation 25. For example, in the first measure, a tempo indication and several ornaments were added.

Here again is the first edition:

[image: Goldberg Variations, First edition, variation 25, measure 1]

And the *handexemplar*:

[image: Goldberg Variations, handexemplar, variation 25, measure 1]

Some additional corroboration is offered by the Henle *Goldberg Variations*, revised edition (1978), which was produced in light of the discovery of the *handexemplar*. The commentary on Variation 25 makes no mention of measure 9.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>All images taken from [ISMLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Goldberg-Variationen,_BWV_988_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian)).</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>The *handexemplar* surfaced in 1975 in a private collection and is currently held by the Bibliothèque Nationale de France. The annotations are discussed in detail in Christoph Wolff's 1976 article "[Bach's 'Handexemplar' of the Goldberg Variations: A New Source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/831018?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)", *Journal of the American Musicological Society* 29/2: 224–41.</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>The Preface, which mentions the *handexemplar*, and the Commentary, can both be found on the [Henle website](https://www.henle.de/us/detail/?Title=Goldberg%20Variations%20BWV%20988_159).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Even the accompanying recording uses an A there:

Furthermore, the G doesn't make a lot of sense.  It's an error.

Comment: I've never known Bach to have any reservations about duplicating / interrupting a note.<g> But even so, Variation 25 is specified for a two-manual instrument, so an "interrupted" G wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ah, good point.  I'll take that out.  It still makes little sense musically.